# How to prevent app from crashing on android emulator

Tags: java, android, operating-system, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am trying to setup an android emulator for pentesting and, I am using the system-image `system-images;android-34;google_apis_playstore;x86_64`. Anytime I try to run Bybit on the emulator, it simply crashes. Here are the logs from logcat

```bash
03-30 17:25:39.576   732   766 V WindowManagerShell: Transition requested: android.os.BinderProxy@259b457 TransitionRequestInfo { type = OPEN, triggerTask = TaskInfo{userId=0 taskId=24 displayId=0 isRunning=true baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.bybit.app cmp=com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity } baseActivity=ComponentInfo{com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} topActivity=ComponentInfo{com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} origActivity=null realActivity=ComponentInfo{com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} numActivities=1 lastActiveTime=1007203 supportsMultiWindow=true resizeMode=2 isResizeable=true minWidth=-1 minHeight=-1 defaultMinSize=220 token=WCT{android.window.IWindowContainerToken$Stub$Proxy@76e7b44} topActivityType=1 pictureInPictureParams=null shouldDockBigOverlays=false launchIntoPipHostTaskId=-1 lastParentTaskIdBeforePip=-1 displayCutoutSafeInsets=null topActivityInfo=ActivityInfo{e31642d com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} launchCookies=[] positionInParent=Point(0, 0) parentTaskId=-1 isFocused=false isVisible=false isVisibleRequested=false isSleeping=false topActivityInSizeCompat=false topActivityEligibleForLetterboxEducation= false topActivityLetterboxed= false isFromDoubleTap= false topActivityLetterboxVerticalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxHorizontalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxWidth=-1 topActivityLetterboxHeight=-1 locusId=null displayAreaFeatureId=1 cameraCompatControlState=hidden}, remoteTransition = null, displayChange = null }
03-30 17:25:39.577   524  2485 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.bybit.app cmp=com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} with LAUNCH_SINGLE_TOP from uid 1000 (BAL_ALLOW_ALLOWLISTED_UID) result code=0
03-30 17:25:39.613   524  2485 D CoreBackPreview: Window{aa89c0c u0 Splash Screen com.bybit.app}: Setting back callback OnBackInvokedCallbackInfo{mCallback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@4af4c5b, mPriority=0, mIsAnimationCallback=false}
03-30 17:25:39.676 11642 11642 I com.bybit.app: Using CollectorTypeCC GC.
03-30 17:25:39.680 11642 11642 W com.bybit.app: Unexpected CPU variant for x86: x86_64.
03-30 17:25:39.680 11642 11642 W com.bybit.app: Known variants: atom, sandybridge, silvermont, goldmont, goldmont-plus, tremont, kabylake, default
03-30 17:25:39.736   524   548 V WindowManager: Sent Transition #41 createdAt=03-30 17:25:39.565 via request=TransitionRequestInfo { type = OPEN, triggerTask = TaskInfo{userId=0 taskId=24 displayId=0 isRunning=true baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.bybit.app cmp=com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity } baseActivity=ComponentInfo{com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} topActivity=ComponentInfo{com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} origActivity=null realActivity=ComponentInfo{com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} numActivities=1 lastActiveTime=1007203 supportsMultiWindow=true resizeMode=2 isResizeable=true minWidth=-1 minHeight=-1 defaultMinSize=220 token=WCT{RemoteToken{10c5337 Task{21b7c99 #24 type=standard A=10190:com.bybit.app}}} topActivityType=1 pictureInPictureParams=null shouldDockBigOverlays=false launchIntoPipHostTaskId=-1 lastParentTaskIdBeforePip=-1 displayCutoutSafeInsets=null topActivityInfo=ActivityInfo{72460a4 com.bybit.pro.MainActivity} launchCookies=[] positionInParent=Point(0, 0) parentTaskId=-1 isFocused=false isVisible=false isVisibleRequested=false isSleeping=false topActivityInSizeCompat=false topActivityEligibleForLetterboxEducation= false topActivityLetterboxed= false isFromDoubleTap= false topActivityLetterboxVerticalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxHorizontalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxWidth=-1 topActivityLetterboxHeight=-1 locusId=null displayAreaFeatureId=1 cameraCompatControlState=hidden}, remoteTransition = null, displayChange = null }
03-30 17:25:39.736   524   548 V WindowManager:     info={id=41 t=OPEN f=0x0 trk=0 r=[0@Point(0, 0)] c=[{WCT{RemoteToken{10c5337 Task{21b7c99 #24 type=standard A=10190:com.bybit.app}}} m=OPEN f=NONE leash=Surface(name=Task=24)/@0xb4725d1 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) d=0},{WCT{RemoteToken{d59c3cd TaskFragment{506e1a4 mode=fullscreen}}} m=TO_BACK f=IN_TASK_WITH_EMBEDDED_ACTIVITY|FILLS_TASK p=WCT{RemoteToken{788222d Task{4f7d95a #22 type=standard A=1000:com.android.settings}}} leash=Surface(name=TaskFragment{506e1a4 mode=fullscreen})/@0x2bae2f7 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) d=0},{WCT{RemoteToken{788222d Task{4f7d95a #22 type=standard A=1000:com.android.settings}}} m=TO_BACK f=NONE leash=Surface(name=Task=22)/@0x176c257 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) d=0}]}
03-30 17:25:39.753   524   564 I ActivityManager: Start proc 11642:com.bybit.app/u0a190 for next-top-activity {com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity}
03-30 17:25:39.950 11642 11642 E com.bybit.app: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
03-30 17:25:40.006 11642 11642 D nativeloader: Configuring clns-6 for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.mdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.bybit.app
03-30 17:25:40.030 11642 11642 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.dm': No such file or directory
03-30 17:25:40.030 11642 11642 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.dm': No such file or directory
03-30 17:25:40.031 11642 11642 W com.bybit.app: Entry not found
03-30 17:25:40.031 11642 11642 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.en.dm': No such file or directory
03-30 17:25:40.031 11642 11642 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.en.dm': No such file or directory
03-30 17:25:40.031 11642 11642 W com.bybit.app: Entry not found
03-30 17:25:40.032 11642 11642 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.mdpi.dm': No such file or directory
03-30 17:25:40.032 11642 11642 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.mdpi.dm': No such file or directory
03-30 17:25:40.032 11642 11642 W com.bybit.app: Entry not found
03-30 17:25:40.033 11642 11642 D nativeloader: Configuring clns-7 for other apk /data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/base.apk:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.en.apk:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.mdpi.apk. target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.mdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt
03-30 17:25:40.057 11642 11642 E LoadedApk: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.mdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.mdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
03-30 17:25:40.057 11642 11642 E LoadedApk:     Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk because: Entry not found
03-30 17:25:40.057 11642 11642 E LoadedApk:     Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.en.apk because: Entry not found
03-30 17:25:40.058 11642 11642 E LoadedApk:     Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/split_config.mdpi.apk because: Entry not found
03-30 17:25:40.081 11642 11642 V GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE GameManagerService for com.bybit.app: false
03-30 17:25:40.082 11642 11642 V GraphicsEnvironment: com.bybit.app is not listed in per-application setting
03-30 17:25:40.100 11642 11642 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.bybit.app, PID: 11642
03-30 17:25:40.100 11642 11642 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/~~oUb8_Qsrt3VQNZpsyjkzMw==/com.bybit.app-4iQh-nGpzVBSYi2bjB9BJA==/lib/arm64/libDexHelper-x86.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
03-30 17:25:40.113   524  1455 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity
03-30 17:25:40.151   524  1455 I ActivityManager: Process com.bybit.app (pid 11642) has died: fg  TOP
03-30 17:25:40.227   524   548 V WindowManager:     info={id=42 t=CLOSE f=0x10 trk=0 r=[0@Point(0, 0)] c=[{WCT{RemoteToken{d59c3cd TaskFragment{506e1a4 mode=fullscreen}}} m=TO_FRONT f=IN_TASK_WITH_EMBEDDED_ACTIVITY|FILLS_TASK p=WCT{RemoteToken{788222d Task{4f7d95a #22 type=standard A=1000:com.android.settings}}} leash=Surface(name=TaskFragment{506e1a4 mode=fullscreen})/@0x2bae2f7 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) d=0},{WCT{RemoteToken{788222d Task{4f7d95a #22 type=standard A=1000:com.android.settings}}} m=TO_FRONT f=MOVE_TO_TOP leash=Surface(name=Task=22)/@0x176c257 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) d=0},{WCT{RemoteToken{10c5337 Task{21b7c99 #24 type=standard A=10190:com.bybit.app}}} m=CLOSE f=NONE leash=Surface(name=Task=24)/@0xb4725d1 sb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 320, 640) d=0}]}
03-30 17:25:40.274   524   596 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'aa89c0c Splash Screen com.bybit.app (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
03-30 17:25:40.617   524   551 W ActivityTaskManager: Activity top resumed state loss timeout for ActivityRecord{54141e0 u0 com.bybit.app/com.bybit.pro.MainActivity t24 f} isExiting}
```

Also I run this app just fine on my device. Please what is wrong and How can I prevent the crashing?

I tried changing emulator with different system image, I got the same result. I tried the system images  `system-images;android-33;google_apis_playstore;x86_64` and  `system-images;android-32;google_apis_playstore;x86_64`

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the app correctly? Based on the posted logcat the app consists of multiple split APK files that have to be installed together e.g. via `adb install-multiple`. My guess is that you only installed base.apk and thus the app is crashing.

Comment: I initially install as base.apk but then I reinstalled from play store. This log is from the APK that was Installed from play store.

Comment: You should better uninstall the app completely and then reinstall it from Play Store. My guess is that it is a bug of Play Store when updating an split app that has been installed with missing splits as you did.